# Application to check ability to access SQL database, based on active directory login?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, active-directory

I have a SQL database which has permissions through active directory groups. My company system to manage AD groups is frankly awful and something which requires tons of my time.

Because of this, I spend... too much time tracking down whether user permission problems are because the AD group didn't add correct, etc.

My simple use case is a simple application which:

- Based on a user's active directory name, check:

  - Can this user connect to the database?

I don't care about roles/permissions on the database other than "can you connect?" at this point. Any user I am testing *should* be in my active directory group allowing access. I have other means to test the entire group/role permissions.

Ideally, for my purposes, I have a simple menu with AD name, database name, and a button that checks whether that user could connect.